# How to alias array elements in CosmosDB documents?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have the following document,

```
{
        "VehicleDetailId": 1,
        "VehicleDetail": [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "Make": "BMW"
            },
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "Model": "ABDS"
            },
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "Trim": "5.6L/ASMD"
            },
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "Year": 2008
            }
        ]
}
```

I want to give aliases for the array elements, something like this,

```
{
        "VehicleDetailId": 1,
        "Type": "VehicleDetail",
        "VehicleDetail": [
            {
                "MakeId": 1,
                "MakeValue": "BMW"
            },
            {
                "ModelId": 1,
                "ModelValue": "ABDS"
            },
            {
                "TrimId": 1,
                "TrimValue": "5.6L/ASMD"
            },
            {
                "YearId": 1,
                "YearValue": 2008
            }
        ]
}
```

The following query seems to work fine, but since Id is common for all, it is repeating every time.

```
SELECT c.vehicleDetailId, ARRAY(SELECT v.Id AS MakeId, v.Make AS MakeValue,
                                       v.Id AS ModelId, v.Model AS ModelValue,
                                       v.Id AS TrimId, v.Trim AS TrimValue,
                                       v.Id AS YearId, v.Year AS YearValue
                                FROM v IN c.VehicleDetail) AS VehicleDetail 
FROM c
```

How should I write the query so that the Id does not repeat every time, and I can fetch an element from a specific position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use UDF to implement your needs.

Udf code:

```
function userDefinedFunction(array){
    var returnArray = [];
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        var obj = array[i];
        var map = {};
        if(obj.Make){
            map["MakeId"]= obj.Id;
            map["MakeValue"]= obj.Make;
        }else if(obj.Model){
            map["ModelId"]= obj.Id;
            map["ModelValue"]= obj.Model;
        }else if(obj.Trim){
            map["TrimId"]= obj.Id;
            map["TrimValue"]= obj.Trim;
        }else if(obj.Year){
            map["YearId"]= obj.Id;
            map["YearValue"]= obj.Year;
        } 
        returnArray.push(map);
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Sql:

```
SELECT c.VehicleDetailId,udf.test(c.VehicleDetail) AS VehicleDetail 
FROM c
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this through just a query, without using a UDF?

Comment: @KajalPatel  I'm afraid that it's impossible so far and i think the udf could be more scalable.

Comment: @KajalPatel I considered `id_defined()` method but it also could not pass through because the column name need to be different as well based on your needs. So maybe you have to consider using UDF or Stored procedure.